# Need to create a median function that draws from a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key-value, median

I need to find the median of all the integers associated with each key (AA, BB).  The basic format my code leads to:

```
AA - 21
AA - 52
BB - 3
BB - 2
```

My code:

```
def scoreData(filename):
   d = dict() 
   fin = open(filename) 
   contents = fin.readlines()
   for line in contents:
       parts = linesplit() 
       part[i] = int(part[1]) 
       if parts[0] not in d:
           d[parts[0]] = list(parts[1])  
       else:
           d[parts[0]].append(parts[1]) 
   names = list(d.keys()) 
   names.sort() #alphabeticez the names
   print("Name\+Max\+Min\+Median")
   for name in names: #makes the table
       print (name"\+", max(d[name]),\+min(d[name]),"\+"median(d[name]))
```

I'm afraid following the same format as the "names" and "names.sort" will completely restructure the data. I've thought about "from statistics import median," but once again I do not know how to only select the values associated with each of the same keys.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with `pandas` and `numpy`:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
```

and aggregating by first row:

```
score = pandas.read_csv(filename, delimiter=' - ', header=None)
print score.groupby(0).agg([np.median, np.min, np.max])
```

which returns:

```
         1
    median  amin  amax
0
AA    36.5    21    52
BB     2.5     2     3
```

Comment: pandas is fun, upvote for you for providing a non-naive solution

Comment: Thanks @cynddl.  I've never heard of pandas before, but it looks amazing for python data analysis! Have a good day :)

Comment: @aruisdante It is more like a bulldozer in this case, but pandas still provides really simple solutions for data analysis!

Answer (score 0):

There are many, **many** ways you can go about this. But here's a 'naive' implementation that will get the job done.

Assuming your data looks like:

```
AA  1
BB  5
AA  2
CC  7
BB  1
```

You can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

def find_averages(input_file)
    result_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for line in input_file.readlines()
        key, value = line.split()
        result_dict[key].append[int(value)]

    return [(key, np.mean(value)) for key,value in result_dict.iteritems()]
```

Comment: I think you mean `from collections import DefaultDict` not just `defaultdict`. This will produce an `ImportError`.

Comment: whopse, yep I sure did

Comment: Another `ImportError`. It's `collections`, not `Collections`. Also you are treating `DefaultDict` like it is a submodule, not a class which it actually is. You need to do the `import` as I said in my first comment.

Comment: bah I can't type today to save my life

Comment: Still won't work, `DefaultDict` is a `class`, not a submodule.

Comment: beat you to it. That's what I get by free-forming it without testing in the iterpreter